# Python Coding for Reversing Sentences

Tags: python, string

this is the code i am using so far.

```
translated = []
line = input('Line: ')
while line != '':
  for word in line.split():
    letters = list(word)
    letters.reverse()
    word = ''.join(letters)
    translated.append(word)
  if line == '':
    print(' '.join(translated))
  elif line:
    line = input('Line: ')
```

it is suppose to read lines of input from the user. An empty line is suppose to signify the end of any inputs. Then the program is suppose to read all the lines, then reproduce them in their original order with each word reversed in place.

```
For example if i was to input: Hello how are you
Its output shout be: olleH woh era uoy
```

Currently it is asking for the inputs, then stopping when there is an empty line, but not producing anything. No reversed words no nothing.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong, and help me out with my code??

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Flav points out to read all lines before an empty line to end the input. I have edited the solution as below:

```
lines = [] # to store all line inputs
while True:
    line = raw_input('Line: ') # input if using python3 or raw_input if python2.6/7
    if line == '':
        break
    lines.append(line)
for line in lines:
    print (' '.join([word[::-1] for word in line.split(' ')]))
```

Comment: I have tested in python2.7 replacing `input` with `raw_input`, and it works. why downvote?

Comment: "An empty line is suppose to signify the end of any inputs. Then the program is suppose to read all the lines, then reproduce them in their original order with each word reversed in place." this is not what your code does.

Comment: @Flav, I even test it in python 3.2.3 and it works perfectly, can you explain why you downvote and question as if it didnt?

Comment: @Flav, ok i re-read OP question and understand what you mean by **lines**, I will edit my post

Comment: OP, could you expand on why you prefered this answer over two similar ones, even though it came ~20 minutes later?

Answer (score 1):

The `print` statement needs to be outside the loop. Your loop condition ensures that `line` is never `''` inside the loop, so the `if` condition is never satisfied.

For the same reason, you need to rethink the `elif`.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it like this.

```
' '.join( [ i[::-1] for i in line.split( ' ' ) ] )
```

1. Split the line into words
2. Reverse each word
3. Put them back together

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when the line is empty, your while loop stops. You should get rid of the if / else which are useless here.

Full script:

```
translated = []
line = input('Line: ')
while line != '':
    for word in line.split():
       letters = list(word)
       letters.reverse()
       word = ''.join(letters)
       translated.append(word)
    #The above for loop could be done in one line with:
    #translated.extend([word[::-1] for word in line.split()])
    line = input('Line: ')

print(' '.join(translated))
```

Answer (score -1):

This works perfect

```
a = "Hello how are you"
" ".join([ "".join(reversed(x)) for x in re.findall('\w+',a) ])
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: ohh sorry, I dident read the full, he wants to reserve the position of the word in this case it will not work, thanks for clarification

Comment: this should work:  
" ".join([ "".join(reversed(x)) for x in re.findall('\w+',a) ])

Comment: @Springrbua the "not an answer" close reason is only for answers that don't attempt to answer a question (such as asking the OP a question). If you think the answer is low-quality, you should downvote it, not vote to close it.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt as much as i know it takes more then one vote to close/delete an answer. In my opinion this post should just be a comment to the question/to another answer, but not an answer itself. If others don't think so, they don't need to close vote and the answer will stay there :)